# WPF and Squirrel deployment on Azure

Tags: wpf, azure, squirrel.windows

I have an application written in WPF (C#) and I deploy this application using Squirrel:

```
https://intellitect.com/deploying-app-squirrel/
```

Now I build application using these commands:

```
.\nuget pack nuget\HelloWorld.nuspec
Squirrel --releasify HelloWorld.1.0.0.nupkg --releaseDir "C:\SquirrelReleases"
```

on my local machine. But my application is stored in Azure.
How to make deployment using Squirrel on Azure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How to make deployment using Squirrel on Azure?

Reading the documentation [`here`](https://github.com/Squirrel/Squirrel.Windows/tree/master/docs), it seems there's no direct way to deploy your files in Azure Storage at least as of answering this question. Even for [`Amazon S3`](https://github.com/Squirrel/Squirrel.Windows/blob/master/docs/using/amazon-s3.md), they are mentioning that you upload the files manually in a s3 bucket:

```
5. upload the files from the Squirrel Releases directory into the S3 bucket.
```

I guess you can do something similar for Azure Storage as well. I have not tried it but I believe this is what you would need to do (based on their documentation for Amazon S3):

1. Create a blob container in your Azure Storage account and set its access level to either `Blob` (recommended) or `Public`.
2. Update the package location on the UpdateManager in your application to use the blob container URL (https://account.blob.core.windows.net/blob-container-name).
3. Upload the files in blob container. There are many options for you to do that from using available storage explorers, or using AzCopy, or using Azure PowerShell/CLI tools or writing code yourself by using any of the available SDKs.